# JAR will not run without Java SE DK

Tags: java

Im trying to make my first real java project,and it seemed to be going fine. I build a JAR and it works fine on my main PC. However, when i move it to my laptop it did not work. I got an a JNI error. I managed to make the program work by installing the DK on my laptop as well, but i thought you only needed a runtime environment.

Im using SE DK 14, and intellliJ IDEA. I tried updating my java version, checking the path variables, but only installing the Developer kit seems to work. Both machines were 64-bit Windows 10 machines

I really want to make it only need the java RE, any ideas?

edit: The exact error is

> "A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again",

followed by

> "A java exception has occurred."

Im using Java 8 update 251 on both devices and Java SE DK 14.0.1 on the device where i made it on. I tried reinstalling , rebuilding and looking into settings of my build, but im not very familiar with Java, maybe i missed something. I just followed [this tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/compiling-applications.html) to make the Jar

Comment: Tell us more details: how you were trying to run your program? what steps did you take to troubleshoot? these will help us help you. :)

Comment: Please edit your question and include the full text of the JNI error—as copied text, please, not as an image.

Comment: You may use [jlink](https://www.baeldung.com/jlink) in order to include *just* the modules that are required by your app.